# Access, For Each loop to add multiple txtfields into table for each row in another table

Tags: ms-access, for-loop, foreach

My question might be confusing, I'm looking for a way to solve issue with 'maintenance' system written in Access.

There is a form with data, and I need to take txtFields values, listBox values and add them as sql row for each phone number that is stored in another table.

For example, dbShift contain few phone numbers (from 8 to 15) and they are switched each 8 hours.

When worker submit form with 'machine failure', maintenance office receives it thru access front-end.

This information need to be added in to another table as well, lets call it dbSMS, where we will store: nrMaszyny, nazwaMaszyny, Zglaszajacy, Przyczyna, Obszar, Telefon.

Now for each phone number stored in dbShift (numbers are switched by the form created for this table) this message needs to be duplicated.

It's all to automate process and send automatically SMS from the modem we have in the company, so maintenance employees will be informed right away about the issue, not only thru their workshop front end.

Everything seems to be done, but I'm stuck with the way of implementing that 'For Each' way to collect neccessary information and add them to table, where modem can feed the data to pass it thru SMS.

Maybe I'm wrong, maybe there is a better way for it than 'For Each'?

Any ideas?

**dbShift**:
ID, name, phoneNumber

**dbSms**:
nrMaszyny, nazwaMaszyny, Zglaszajacy, Przyczyna, Obszar, Telefon (data from FORM where worker sends machine failure form)

form from where You collect data:
[image: Form]

Code of this form:

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub buttonZamknijFormrularz_Click()

    DoCmd.Close DoCmd.OpenForm "MainLoginForm"
    Forms!MainLoginForm!txtPassword.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

    If IsNull(Me.listPrzyczyna) Or Me.listPrzyczyna = "" Then
        MsgBox "Wybierz przyczynę awarii!", vbOKOnly, "Wymagane dane"
        Me.listPrzyczyna.SetFocus

    Else

        Dim strSQL As String

        strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbAwarieOtwarte (nrMaszyny, nazwaMaszyny, Zglaszajacy, dataZgloszenia, dataZakonczenia,
            godzinaZgloszenia, Przyczyna, Obszar, Telefon, Komentarz) VALUES ('" &
            Me!txtNrMaszyny & "', '" & Me!txtNazwa & "', '" & Me!txtZglaszajacy &
            "', '" & Me!txtData & "', '" & Me!txtData & "', '" & Me!txtGodzina &
            "', '" & Me!listPrzyczyna & "," & Me!txtNazwa & "," & Me!txtNrMaszyny
            & "," & Me!txtObszar & "', '" & Me!txtObszar & "', '" & Me!txtTel &
            "', '" & Me!txtKomentarz & "');"

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        DoCmd.Close '        DoCmd.OpenReport "repAwariaOtwarta", acViewPreview, , "ID=" & DMax("ID", "dbAwarieOtwarte")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Polecenie35_Click() 
    DoCmd.Close DoCmd.OpenForm "formMaszynyObszar1" 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show table structure (fields, keys, and data types). You can simply use an inner join `SELECT` query matching all phone numbers (so resultset will repeat phone numbers as needed). Then, use that select statement in an `INSERT INTO` append query.

Comment: Filled all neccessary info i think.

Comment: All the informations passed are strings and/or integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest modifying your code to do something like the following... You said there is another table with phone numbers, so I will loop thru that table.  Not sure if you want to use DAO or ADO, so I stuck with DAO.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim dbs as DAO.Database
Dim rsPhone as DAO.Recordset

If IsNull(Me.listPrzyczyna) Or Me.listPrzyczyna = "" Then
    MsgBox "Wybierz przyczynę awarii!", vbOKOnly, "Wymagane dane"
    Me.listPrzyczyna.SetFocus

Else
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set dbs = CurrentDB
    Set rsPhone = dbs.OpenRecordset("<YourPhoneTable>")
    Do While Not rsPhone.EOF

'<<< MAKE YOUR CHANGES TO GRAB THE PHONE NUMBER if needed for the following SQL
' 3/10/16 - changed SQL to add phonenumber to the insert.

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbAwarieOtwarte (nrMaszyny, nazwaMaszyny, Zglaszajacy, dataZgloszenia, dataZakonczenia,
        godzinaZgloszenia, Przyczyna, Obszar, Telefon, Komentarz, PhoneNumber) VALUES ('" &
        Me!txtNrMaszyny & "', '" & Me!txtNazwa & "', '" & Me!txtZglaszajacy &
        "', '" & Me!txtData & "', '" & Me!txtData & "', '" & Me!txtGodzina &
        "', '" & Me!listPrzyczyna & "," & Me!txtNazwa & "," & Me!txtNrMaszyny
        & "," & Me!txtObszar & "', '" & Me!txtObszar & "', '" & Me!txtTel &
        "', '" & Me!txtKomentarz & "', '" & rsPhone!PhoneNumber & "');"

        'DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        dbs.Execute strSQL
        'DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        rsPhone.moveNext
    Loop
    rsPhone.Close
    set rsPhone = Nothing
    dbs.close
    set dbs = Nothing
    DoCmd.Close '        DoCmd.OpenReport "repAwariaOtwarta", acViewPreview, , "ID=" & DMax("ID", "dbAwarieOtwarte")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello!

My apologizes for such long response, I had to be offline for some time. I will give it a shot today! :)

Comment: Its awesome, its looping, adding to the table. How can i add rsPhone as a Value? Each loop is caused by another phone table row. I want my strSQL to add looped phone number as a value to the database. Is it possible? Not quite sure how to refer to rsPhone in my strSQL insert.

Comment: I don't know the target field name of 'PhoneNumber', so will assume it is that name. If different, you need to change the name or tell me what it is. I have modified above answer to change the SQL string to include phone.